# CSS Make a specific image appear on a specific navigation bar hover

Tags: html, css

I need to make it so if I have a navigation bar with Home, Oil, Coal and Natural gas, when I hover over oil, it'll make the background image for that box an oil drop or something, and if I hover over coal it will have the background image for coal in that specific box.

This is my code so far, but it's currently showing same image (oil) no matter what I hover over:

```css
#NavBar ul {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
#NavBar li {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#NavBar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
#NavBar a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: url("billeder/olie_navbar.png");
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Hjem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="olie.html">Olie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="kul.html">Kul</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="naturgas.html">Naturgas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Create an id for each navbutton and do them separately in css.

Comment: So i should be doing like <li><a id="index" href="index.html">Home</a></li> and so on? Or how should it be coded properly to work?

Comment: Yup, now do the same thing but with id-s, not tags in css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an ID or a class for each item in your navigation, like so:

```
<div id="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Hjem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="olie" href="olie.html">Olie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="kul" href="kul.html">Kul</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="naturgas" href="naturgas.html">Naturgas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then assign a `background-image` accordingly:

```
#NavBar olie:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: url("billeder/olie_navbar.png");
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}


#NavBar kul:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: url("billeder/kul_navbar.png");
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}


#NavBar naturgas:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: url("billeder/naturgas_navbar.png");
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

This way each `a` tag can has a different hover state

Answer (score 0):

You should give each a element its own id. Then give each id the background-image according to its id.

```css
#Hjem:hover{
  background-image: url("Hjem.png");
}

#Olie:hover{
  background-image: url("Olie.png");
}

#Kul:hover{
  background-image: url("Kul.png");
}

#Naturgas:hover{
  background-image: url("Naturgas.png");
}

#NavBar ul {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
#NavBar li {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#NavBar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

#NavBar a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="Hjem" href="index.html">Hjem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="Olie" href="olie.html">Olie</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="Kul" href="kul.html">Kul</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="Naturgas" href="naturgas.html">Naturgas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So your markup doesn't really allow for any specific targeting of individual tags, - basically your css targets every list item, instead of a specific list item.

I've made some modifications to your code,
 - added a class to each of your li tags
 - added a css selector for each of your classes

Hopefully you can see where to take it from here.

```css
li.hjem a:hover {
  background-image: url("billeder/hjem_navbar.png");
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
li.olie a:hover {
  background-image: url("billeder/olie_navbar.png");
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
li.kul a:hover {
  background-image: url("billeder/kul_navbar.png");
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
li.Naturgas a:hover {
  background-image: url("billeder/Naturgas_navbar.png");
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li class="hjem"><a href="index.html">Hjem</a>
    </li>
    <li class="olie"><a href="olie.html">Olie</a>
    </li>
    <li class="kul"><a href="kul.html">Kul</a>
    </li>
    <li class="naturgas"><a href="naturgas.html">Naturgas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```